# Thesis statements or theses statements?

Tags: word-choice

I am doing research for three different questions and I am going to present one single thesis statement for each question. Would I refer to all three statements as 'thesis statements' or as 'theses statements'?

Intuitively, I would choose the latter as both the total number of statements and questions are plural. Which one is correct though?

Comment: "Theses statements" sounds wrong to me, and it looks like it is almost never used compared to "thesis statements": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thesis+statements%2C+theses+statements&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthesis%20statements%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctheses%20statements%3B%2Cc0

Comment: ***Thesis*** here is a [*noun adjunct*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) or *attributive noun* or *noun (pre)modifier*. So pluralizing it would be just as "unidiomatic" as talking about ***cars** radios*, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this site (https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/545/01/), it's 'thesis statements' (plural only for statement). I think this link from Indiana University is more reliable: http://www.indiana.edu/~wts/pamphlets/thesis_statement.shtml. Just look for 'thesis statements' at the pages.